# I have a desktop iMac when I log in in just goes straight to utilities

Tags: macos

But when I try to reinstall macOS Sierra it won't load says unable to mount. Then it says a re over disk is locked when I am in utilizes it doesn't give option to view all devices just let's me select hitashi or osbase an even when I partial it still doesn't let me reinstall it. Then says something about no volumes . An I cant select anything nor can I even reinstall mac HD.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  Could you use the edit button to make clear one specific question you wish to be answered. There is some detail, but we need to know clearly (hopefully without too many typos) what end goal is desired and not have to guess your intentions

Answer (score 0):

Because you didn't specify, I'm going to guess from the fact that you wrote "Sierra" that you have an Intel-based iMac.

I suggest trying to [boot the machine in Recovery Mode](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/use-macos-recovery-on-an-intel-based-mac-mchl338cf9a8/14.0/mac/14.0#mchl69906860) and [reinstalling macOS](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/use-macos-recovery-on-an-intel-based-mac-mchl338cf9a8/14.0/mac/14.0#mchlde1a4fd2) from there. Let us know how that goes, and update your question when you can. Adding some screenshots for context would also be helpful.

If there's something preventing the normal disk-based Recovery from booting, try one of the internet-based recovery modes:

| keys (press + hold simultaneously) | what that does... |
| --- | --- |
| <kbd>⌥opt</kbd><kbd>⌘cmd</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> | reinstalls the latest version of macOS that’s compatible with your Mac |
| <kbd>⇧shift</kbd><kbd>⌥opt</kbd><kbd>⌘cmd</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> | reinstalls the version of macOS that came with your Mac, or the closest version that’s still available |

And if all else fails, [this post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/309399/how-can-i-download-an-older-version-of-os-x-macos) has a very in-depth list of means and methods for reinstalling all variants of macOS.